# rolling mean series - strong autocorrelation

Tags: least-squares, autocorrelation, moving-window, overlapping-data

I need to works with time-series of rolling means of a certain variable that comes from the data. I have this rolling means for N different individuals. Call them Y. I would like to test some explanatory variables for Y, call them X, which are K features of the individuals for which Y is recorded. X are not rolling means (but one could calculate rolling means also for X).

When I run cross-sectional regressions to explain Y using X, the standard errors for the OLS coefficients od some Xs are extremely small, giving rise to huge t-statistics. Likewise, if I run classical t-test for the means of Y, the t-statistics are extremely large (like above 20). I guess the issue lies in the fact that the Y are extremely autocorrelated (at the individual level), because indeed they are rolling means computed with quite long rolling windows. The first order autocorrelation is for example 0.96, and even at the 10th lag it is still around 0.70.

If my purpose is find good explanatory variables for Y, is there something that I can do to sidestep this problem? For example, what would you think about demeaning Y (at the individual level) so that what is left are deviations from means? Unfortunately this solution would not do anything against the autocorrelation problem, though. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Why not work with the original data?  Using the rolling means is a strong violation of OLS independence assumptions *by construction,* whereas it's possible the original data might have errors that are approximately independent.

Comment: @whuber good point. Unfortunately I need to use rolling means because I do not have access to the original data. The data provider makes available rolling means to "smooth" series that would be otherwise too volatile. But that is not something I can personally deal with unfortunately

Comment: Do you know how many observations are in each rolling mean?

Comment: I believe @jbowman's point is that you can almost recover the original data if you know the window size.  And you might even be able to guess the size by examining the serial correlations of the differences at lags 1, 2, 3, and so on: when they suddenly drop would likely indicate the window length.

Comment: @whuber - yes, and, with $L$ observations in the rolling mean, first differencing results in the series $y^*_t = y_t - y_{t-L}$, so differencing $X$ with lag $L$ might enable a useful regression.

Comment: @jbowman I did a quick study.  The difference at which the lag-1 pacf first becomes insignificant signals the window width but it's pretty uncertain unless the time series is quite long (many thousands of steps).  Even so, this does offer a principled way of deriving a new and perhaps more tractable response variable from the given one, even if it doesn't exactly deconvolve the windowed mean.

Comment: Huh, interesting, I would have guessed otherwise.  It seems as though the  OP has multiple series, and if the window width is the same for each (and they have enough of them) perhaps averaging the pacfs would sharpen the estimates enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the width of the moving average window, you can undo a lot of the damage done by the construction of rolling means.

Let the window width be denoted by $L$. Forming a new target variable $y^*_t$ by differencing the existing one ($y^*_t = y_t - y_{t-1}$) greatly reduces the correlation in the target variable.  This constructs the series we would have seen had we a) had the original data, say $w_t$, and b) differenced it at $L$ periods: $y^*_t = w_t - w_{t-L}$. We then difference the right hand side variable(s) $x_t$ with lag $L$ to form $x^*_t = x_t - x_{t-L}$; this allows us to run a regression on relatively uncorrelated target variables with the time indices and differencing aligned.  An example in R follows:

First, we construct the data:

```
library(data.table)

x_orig <- 5*runif(140)
y_orig <- x_orig + rnorm(140)

L <- 7
y <- frollmean(y_orig, n=L, align="right")
```

The initial observations in `y` are filled with `NA` values, so, at this point, `y`, `y_orig`, and `x_orig` all have the same number of observations.  Note that the observations for `x_orig` line up with the rolling mean of `y_orig` through the same time period - the rolling means are right-aligned, in the parlance of the function we've used.

The relationship between the original $y$ and $x$ values looks like:

[image]

... but the relationship between the rolling mean and the $x$ values looks like:
[image]

We now execute the procedure described above:

```
y <- y[!is.na(y)]                     # Remove the NA values from y
dy <- (y[2:(N-L+1)] - y[1:(N-L)]) * L # Multiply by L as the rolling mean divides all the data by L
dx <- x_orig[(1+L):N] - x_orig[1:(N-L)]

regr  <- lm(dy~dx)
summary(regr)

    Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.01364    0.10536    0.13    0.897    
dx           0.95952    0.04969   19.31   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.214 on 131 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:   0.74, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7381 
F-statistic: 372.9 on 1 and 131 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

As we can see, the coefficient estimate for `dx` is almost the same as the true value of 1.0.

However, we can do better than this by taking into account the remaining autocorrelation in the data.  Let's look at an autocorrelation plot of the residuals from the regression:

[image]

As we can see, there is some autocorrelation at a lag of 7 periods, which corresponds to our window width $L=7$.  The `arima` function enables us to run a regression taking this into account:

```
arima_regr <- arima(dy, seasonal= list(order=c(1,0,0), period=L), xreg=dx)
arima_regr

Coefficients:
         sar1  intercept      dx
      -0.4247     0.0120  0.9833
s.e.   0.0805     0.0677  0.0489
```

In this case, the coefficient estimates and their standard errors did not change much, except for the standard error of the intercept.  I would expect this to be the case for $L$ small relative to the total number of observations, as it is here, and, if so, it may  not be worth building the `arima` model at all.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach I did not think about. In my sample, where I know the window width it 120 (and the rolling time series as about 400 data points for each of the N individuals), taking the first difference already pushes the correlation close to zero

Comment: If it answers your question sufficiently well, please accept it; that will let future searchers for similar information know that there is a helpful answer here!